# Richard Feynman - QED: The Strange Theory of Matter and Light

Tags: visible-light, quantum-electrodynamics, history, matter

After reading the book *[QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED:_The_Strange_Theory_of_Light_and_Matter)*, an adaptation of four lectures Richard Feynman gave at the University of Auckland, I gained a greater understanding of QED. I am not a professional physicist in any capacity, it is just an interest of mine.

However, his lectures were given back in 1979, and the book was published in 1985. Since then, obviously, things have changed, and discoveries have been made.

What things in his book are now different or untrue because of a modern discovery or an advancement in a particular theory?

Comment: This seems a bit too broad to fit in here IMHO. Anyway, that lectures were aimed at non-scientists, and therefore Feynman's intention is to amaze his audience, not to provide an accurate description of physics. What he says is far from what physicists actually believe QFT to mean. In other words, most of that book is untrue in a sense, not because of modern discoveries but because it was untrue back then as well. [in any case, the magnetic moment of the electron is known to many more figures than when Feynman wrote that, so that's something different]

Comment: What's changed? Physics isn't as entertaining, imo ....... Seriously, a much better place is for your question is http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CountTo10 Upon reading the Tour pages for both the Physics SE and [History of Science and Mathematics](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/tour) SE, I still think that this question belongs here. This question is not as much about the history of physics, but instead about what is untrue now in modern physics (it doesn't concern past physics, just what is known today). However, this is just my understanding of it.

Comment: Two quibbles, no offence meant.  The semantic one, history is up to yesterday. The second is more pragmatic and hopefully more useful and ultimately helpful to you, the question will probably be closed because it's too broad and too open to personal opinion. I will retract my vote, let others decide on the basis of your comment above. I wish you the best with your question. Regards

Comment: QED hasn't changed much in the last 40 years. For a non-expert, the lectures are still just about the best non-technical introduction to QED.

Answer (score 4):

I can name three.

1. He says that a spin-0 particle has yet to be found experimentally. We have found the Higgs boson, which is spin-0.
2. He says that the Weinberg-Salam electroweak theory is still imperfect. Today, it is a part of the standard model, and is widely accepted (also, the Higgs boson, a big part of the theory, has been found)
3. Feynman reduces QED (and QFT in general) to the addition of amplitudes from Feynman-diagrams. This is called perturbative QFT. It has since become accepted that QFT has more to offer than just perturbation theory (e.g. solitons, instantons).